# C++ Multiple Client Socket in 1 or 2 threads

Tags: c++, sockets

How would I go about doing this. All in single thread

Basically, a "ClientClass" needs to have 10 nonblocking sockets. A socket will connect to a server every 100ms.

For example if I have `socketlist[9], socketlist[0]` will try to connect, then after 100ms `socketlist[1]` will connect and so on.

Client will continue to try to connect until it is fully logged in. Once one socket is connected:

1. save that socket position and close the rest of the sockets in that list;
2. close other sockets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Why do you need multiple sockets for this? Just have one socket and keep trying to reconnect with that one?

Comment: The answer is `select()` or `epoll()`, depending on your undisclosed platform, but this is too broad,

Comment: Method one: crack open an editor and start writing code. When you are blocked by a *specific* problem, ask a question here.